# Remove rows that are not relevant for my data set

Tags: pandas, dataframe, delete-row

Consider the following pandas dataframe which contains info about the usage of the public pool by a single user.

He can only use the service twice per week, so when he reaches 2 usages, the rest of the days within the same week are automatically 0. How can I delete this irrelevant rows, i.e., all the rows that fulfil df['Attended']==0 because the threshold has been reached?

```
Week Day Attended?
1     1      0
1     2      1
1     3      1
1     4      0
1     5      0
2     1      1
2     2      1
2     3      0
2     4      0
2     5      0
3     1      0
3     2      0
3     3      0
3     4      0
3     5      1
```

As an example, the expected output would delete days 4,5 from week1 as the threshold is reached on day 3. In the same manner, the threshold is reached on day 2 for week 2 so day 3,4 and 5 are deleted.

```
Week Day Attended?
1     1      0
1     2      1
1     3      1
2     1      1
2     2      1
3     1      0
3     2      0
3     3      0
3     4      0
3     5      1
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['Attended']==1]]` OR `df.loc[df['Attended']!=0]]` ?

Comment: Wouldn't this command also delete zeros prior to the 2 times usage of the service? I just want to get rid of the zeros that occur, for every week, after the accumulated 'Attended' is equal to 2 or when there is no more 1s in the corresponding week.

Comment: Can you post Expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Form a Boolean mask with `cumsum` to find the `0`s after the first 2 attendances. Subset with `.loc`

```
m = df.groupby('Week')['Attended?'].cumsum().ge(2) & df['Attended?'].eq(0)
df.loc[~m]
```

---

```
    Week  Day  Attended?
0      1    1          0
1      1    2          1
2      1    3          1
5      2    1          1
6      2    2          1
10     3    1          0
11     3    2          0
12     3    3          0
13     3    4          0
14     3    5          1
```

---

To do this with a variable threshold per week, as in your comments, we `map` then can use the same logic, checking against the created column, not a scalar value.

```
thresh = [1, 2, 2]  # Usages per week to drop after
week = [1, 2, 3]

df['threshold'] = df['Week'].map(dict(zip(week, thresh)))

m = df.groupby('Week')['Attended?'].cumsum().ge(df['threshold']) & df['Attended?'].eq(0)
df.loc[~m]

    Week  Day  Attended?  threshold
0      1    1          0          1
1      1    2          1          1
2      1    3          1          1
5      2    1          1          2
6      2    2          1          2
10     3    1          0          2
11     3    2          0          2
12     3    3          0          2
13     3    4          0          2
14     3    5          1          2
```

Comment: Nice answer. Would the approach be valid for a variable threshold across the weeks? i.e., having the number of allowed days in an array [n1, n2, n3]  for weeks [1,2,3], respectively?

Comment: @Jos Yes. In that case I would `map` the threshold to a new column based on week (let's call it 'threshold'), then you can check if the cumsum is `.ge(df.threshold)`. I can update the solution in like 45 minutes with an example to show that.

Comment: I only wish that I could upvote it more than once!!